# Raspberry Pi B FreeBSD 11.2 does not boot with USB pendrive inserted

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive, freebsd

I am trying to install FreeBSD on a Raspberry Pi B (not 2 or 3, the old one).
I prepared an SD card with the FreeBSD 11.2 image from download.freebsd.org/ftp/snapshots/arm/armv6/ISO-IMAGES/ and booted the Pi with it. This seems to work fine. Then I added a USB pendrive, and used `gpart` to make a `GPT` `freebsd-ufs` partition on the whole drive.

Now when I reboot the Pi with the pendrive inserted it does not boot any more. When I remove the pendrive it boots fine again.

Below are some photos of the information on screen. (Sorry for fussy photos, I do not know how to take screenshots on FreeBSD when it does not boot.)
It seems that U-Boot detects the USB pendrive and, somehow believes that it should boot from it.

I would like to change it to "always boot from the sd card", but I do not know how.

Any tips?

Booting without pendrive
[image: Booting without pendrive]

Not booting with pendrive
[image: Not booting with pendrive]

gpart
[image: gpart]